# Unsure how resistors are connected? (Series/Parallel)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I am currently attempting this practice question in my tutorial and while I am able to reduce the circuit below to

[image]

I do not know whether the 6/6/6/6 pane is connected in series or parallel, it should not be parallal else R(Total) = 3+3+3 and Vo will be 2/3 * 12 = 4

The answer im expecting is 4/3V so my current attempt is wrong. I also doubt it is a Wye-Delta transformation. Can anyone explain how the resistors are connected and why? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to change the right corner since the $V_o$ is taken from a voltage divider in that region.

Comment: You need to combine your 2 posts since one of them will be suspended.

Comment: ^Thats a good point, well I thought it would be great if i redid the whole question posting over so the admin can approve of it, always better to start over fresh I guess.

Comment: You can edit your own posts and add to them.

Comment: Please use the edit facilities rather than re-posting.